# Is there an equivalent for server side .gitattributes in Azure DevOps?

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

My team maintains a JSON file with a dictionary of GUIDs to version images our service consumes correctly. Two developers can have distinct changes but for the same entry, so when they overwrite the same line in the file, then whoever commits later has a merge conflict.

We use Azure DevOps and I want to use .gitattributes to effectively always "merge ours" in just this file when completing a pull request. However, it seems Azure DevOps is not honoring this server side because attempting to complete a pull request will still fail even with the .gitattributes file.

There was a [similar User Voice request](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/330519-azure-devops-formerly-visual-studio-team-services/suggestions/35354191--gitattributes-not-applied-on-pull-request) but it was from a while ago.

Is there another way we can achieve similar behavior to prevent having to do an often unnecessary and time-consuming one-line merge conflict resolution with Azure DevOps?

Comment: Your link is broken. Do you mean this: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/65693/gitattributes-not-applied-on-pull-request.html

Answer (score 0):

There is an extension that allows to resolve such merge conflict in the browser.

[Pull Request Merge Conflict Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-devlabs.conflicts-tab)

This improves this issue a little bit.